# How does Ruby know the variable belongs to this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know how Ruby knows which variable is assigned to certain codes. For example in this code:

```
print "What's your first name?"
first_name = gets.chomp
first_name.capitalize!

print "What's your last name?"
last_name = gets.chomp
last_name.capitalize!

print "What city are you from?"
city = gets.chomp
city.capitalize!

print "What state or province are you from?"
state = gets.chomp
state.upcase!

puts "Your name is #{first_name} #{last_name} and you're from #{city}, #{state}!"
```

How does Ruby know that the `city` variable is the answer of the users input from the question "What city are you from?"?

Answer (score 1):

The `gets` method reads a line from standard input, and returns that as a string.  `chomp` is then called on the result of `gets` (the string that it just read).  The result is then assigned to a variable (`city`, `state`, etc.).

The method `capitalize!` actually *modifies* the object that it is called on.  After `city.capitalize!`, the string referred to by `city` has been modified (capitalized).  This is different from returning a modified version of an object (which is what happens during `gets.chomp`, where the result of `gets` never gets stored anywhere, it is immediately modified by `chomp` and the result of *that* is then stored).

To further clarify: every call to `gets` reads a new string from the console, which is then `chomp`ed and stored in a variable.  This is why your program asks for several inputs and keeps them all around in those variables.

Comment: But how does first_name store the answer for the question "What is your first name?". I'm coming from a Javascript/JQuery background, so when I started Ruby I realized it's a completely different ball field.

Comment: Strings in ruby are a class instance.  You can call actions on them directly.  Like "Every other word".split(" ") will return a list of words split by spaces.  Most things in ruby work like this.  You can do last_name.methods to see what methods are available to that string instance, and then use them. (last_name being a string you already created)

Comment: You can create a string instance like a="" or a = String.new ... these are the same thing.  It's fun working with different elements as objects. ['1','2'].join(" ") will return the string "1 2".  You can also use the .to_s method.  For example 123.to_s returns "123".

Comment: The answer to the question is read by the call to `gets`, then modified with `chomp`, and the result of that is then stored in `first_name`. In Javascript is would look like `var first_name = gets().chomp()`.  Not that different, actually.